# Simple jQuery Carousel looping through as it should

Tags: jquery, carousel

I have a simple jQuery carousel effect that I am trying to make. The carousel works perfectly if you click on the left button, but breaks after it loops through the four items on the right.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$("div.slider_controls .go_right").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if( $(".home_slider ul li.current").next().size() != 0 ) 
    {
        $(".home_slider ul li.current").animate({ marginLeft: '-=25%'}, 1000).removeClass("current").next().addClass("current");
    }
    else
    {
        var $first = $(".home_slider ul li:first");
        $('.home_slider ul li:last').after($($first));
        $($first).css({'margin-left' : '+25%'});
        $(".home_slider ul li.current").removeClass("current").next().animate({ marginLeft: '-=25%'}, 1000).addClass("current");
    }
});

$("div.slider_controls .go_left").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if( $(".home_slider ul li.current").prev().size() != 0 ) 
    {
        $(".home_slider ul li.current").removeClass("current").prev().animate({ marginLeft: '+=25%'}, 1000).addClass("current");
    }
    else
    {
        var $last = $(".home_slider ul li:last");
        $($last).css({'margin-left' : '-25%'});
        $('.home_slider ul li:first').before($($last));
        $(".home_slider ul li.current").removeClass("current").prev().animate({ marginLeft: '+=25%'}, 1000).addClass("current");
    }

});
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="home_slider">
        <ul>
            <li class="current"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/home_photo1.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/home_photo2.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/home_photo3.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/home_photo4.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div class="slider_controls">
            <a href="#" class="go_left">Previous</a>
            <a href="#" class="go_right">Next</a>
        </div>
```

If you have any ideas as to what the problem could be I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The code blocks for your 'prev' and 'next' buttons differ - you're removing the 'current' class earlier in the chain when clicking on the 'prev' button. As this is working as expected, try mirroring your code - take the 'prev' code, and alter it to work the opposite way.

Comment: This wouldn't effect the problem, because most of the issues are happening in the else block, once the DOM is out of items to cycle through.

Comment: I managed to find the solution. I was doing this:

    $(".home_slider ul li:last").css({'margin-left' : '+25%'});

and I needed to do this

    $(".home_slider ul li.current").next().css({'margin-left' : '0'});